# Using hash directly in methods from unordered_map instead of the user defined object producing the hash

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-map

So i have created a class that i use as a hash in an unordered_map

```cpp
class MyClass
{
  hash_type mHash = 0;
  hash_type hash() { return mHash; }

  bool operator!= (const MyClass& rhs) const;
  bool operator== (const MyClass& rhs) const;
}
namespace std
{
    template <>
    struct hash<MyClass>
    {
        hash_type operator()(const MyClass& k) const noexcept
        {
            return k.hash();
        }
    };
}
```

It works as expected but i would like to add some functionality.
I would like to be able to use the hash itself when using unordered_map functions like find and erase.
Now i have to do this:

```cpp
void _erase_key(const MyClass& key) { umap.erase(key); }
```

But i would like to be able to do this as well:

```cpp
void _erase_key(const hash_type key) { umap.erase(key); }
```

Is it possible to somehow use the hash directly instead of the object producing the hash when using methods like find and erase?

Comment: Short Answer: No.  Think about hash collisions.  Which object should you delete if there is a colision?

Comment: @NathanOliver There shouldn't be any hash collisions since then they should not have been added in the first place?

Comment: can you write a conversion from `hash_type` to `MyClass`?

Comment: There are always going to be hash collisions (well unless you know your data set and can come up with a perfect hash.  Lets says you are storing `int`'s, and you have a really bad hash algorithm that does `value % 100`.  Then `100`, `200`, `300` would all hash to the same value.  The actual objects though would still be inserted since the map using `==` (or a provided comparator) to check if the objects are actually equal or not.  Make sense?

Comment: @NathanOliver Sure its possible that the hash might be hash collisions. But the == operator is overridden to check if the hash is the same and not the object itself.

Comment: @objectnabb Right, so if you have **just the hash**, which object in my above scenario would you delete?

Comment: @NathanOliver if the key hash produced by MyClass is 123. If I then provide 123 that key should be deleted.

Comment: @objectnabb What if two non-equal `MyClass` both produce `123` as the hash.  What do you do then?

Comment: @NathanOliver What is the difference from any hash?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Thank you! That worked well. I'm going to leave this open for a while in case someone can provide another "better" solution.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you right, you want to have an `std::unordered_map<MyClass, Value>` such that you can also query with `hash_type` and you have `hash_type h == MyClass m` if `std::hash<MyClass>{}(m) == h`. Is this correct?

This is not possible in C++17. With C++20, there will be added the functionality of *transparent hashes*. You can read about that very briefly [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find). With this, your map has to fulfill certain properties

- Your equality type `Eq` must provide a member type `Eq::is_transparent`, i.e. you have to put a `using is_transparent = some_type;` in it. (The exact type is without consequence.)
- An object of type `Eq` has to provide an overload to compare all possible combinations of types you want to use. I.e. provide overloads for `(MyClass, MyClass)` and `(MyClass, hash_type)`.
- Your hash type `Hash` has to provide a member type `Hash::transparent_key_equal`, so again, put `using transparent_key_equal = some_type;` in it.
- An object of type `Hash` must be callable with every type you want to use. I.e. you have to have an `operator()` overload for both `MyClass` and `hash_type`.

For `Eq` you can use `std::equal_to<>` (note the empty diamond!) if you provide publically accessible `operator==` for the appropriate types. This is **NOT** the default for `unordered_map`.

There is to the best of my knowledge no analagon for `std::hash`, so you have to add an own type for that and provide it to the map.

Pre-C++20 the only thing you can do if you want to keep your key type is to write a conversion from `hash_type` to `MyClass`.

But I sense a fundamental problem in this, namely that you see two objects of `MyClass` as identical if they have the same hash. If this is unintentional, you should really fix this. If it is intentional, make sure, that `operator==(MyClass, MyClass)` also only compares hashes.

In the later case, there is an easy fix for your problem. Change your map to `std::unordered_map<hash_type, Value>` and hash each `MyClass` you use to query the map. If you need a reverse lookup to get `MyClass` from a hash, either write a conversion function from `hash_type` to `MyClass` if this is possible, otherwise add another `std::unordered_map<hash_type, MyClass>`, where you store every object of type `MyClass` you ever use.